# Efficiency of storing file size vs calculating it every time?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, filesystems

I have a system for a file hosting site which requires a PHP script to send out the http headers for MIME type and content length of the file.

The problem I'm facing is: would be better to store the MIME type and filesize in the database with the image's entry or to calculate it using filesize() and mime_content_type() on every hit.

I am judging 'better' based on the fastest possible load time but I would like to avoid redundant data and excessive row size if the speed increase is pointless.

Comment: Or if there is some form of standard best practice or something?

Comment: image: 1000-1000000 bytes.  File size: 4 bytes.  MIME type [text]: ~10 bytes.  MIME type [enum]: 1 byte.  I don't think that would make the row size much worse...

Comment: I understand that storing it takes relatively no space, I'm more concerned about redundant data

Comment: You should probably remove all of your indexes as well then.  Those are all redundant data.  The question is if that redundant data helps you serve requests more quickly.

Comment: @MitchellGrice:  What does the future hold for evolution of the protocol?  Would it eventually also include create/modify times, SHA-256 hash value, exif tag contents, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you handling thousands, millions or billions of images?

If thousands, then store it in the database. (If you end up serving the same images a large number of times, then it should be a net saving of disk-IO)

If millions or billions, then properly measure it by profiling both solutions (AB testing) with your real traffic. There are likely too many performance variables in the rest of your code to know for sure!

Comment: Somewhere in between, tens to hundreds of thousands

Comment: Without knowing your traffic, I'd be inclined to go with storing them in the database.